# Unable to build wireless-regb and crda packages on Debian 9 “Stretch” from sources

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, hostapd

Ok, so the problem is, the regulations i get with the stock wireless-regdb for my country are incorect. In fact, it's not even close to the regulations we got. We're allowed to use 13 channel (2472 MHz), and, of course, we're allowed to use transmit power over 20 dBm. And since my wlan adapter is capable of 1W, i want to take that advantage and use 30 dBm. The way i see it - the most simple solution is to get them sources of those debian packages, correct the regulations, rebuild deb packages and to install them. That's what i've done years ago on Debian 7 (Wheezy), and it worked like a charm. That's not the case on Debian 9. The build ends with no failures, i get two shiny new packages, but they just don't work. I get country 00 with iw reg get. I bet i'm doing something wrong with them keys i need to sign regulatory.bin file, probably something has change since Wheezy. These are my steps:

Install pbuilder, get the sources and install required dependencies

```
apt-get update
apt-get install pbuilder
apt-get source wireless-regdb crda
apt-get build-dep wireless-regdb crda
```

Generate my keypair

```
openssl genrsa -out ~/.wireless-regdb-andy.key.priv.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in ~/.wireless-regdb-andy.key.priv.pem -out andy.key.pub.pem -pubout -outform PEM

cd wireless-regdb-2016.06.10
vi debian/rules (change REGDB_AUTHOR to andy, that's for the key)
vi db.txt (edit the regulations to the correct values)
```

Make new regulatory.bin and sign it with my private key

```
./db2bin.py regulatory.bin db.txt ~/.wireless-regdb-andy.key.priv.pem
```

Copy public key to crda

```
cp ../andy.key.pub.pem ../crda-3.18/pubkeys/
```

Build them packages

```
debuild -i -us -uc -b
cd ../crda-3.18/
debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

That's it. They build, but they don't work.